# How to use JSON file as a JS object without importing it to the webpack compiled code?

Tags: json, angular, webpack, import

During bootstrap of my Angular hybrid app (Angular7 and AngularJS working side by side). I want to use my config from a separate config json file as a window variable. At the moment I'm using:

```
setAngularLib(AngularJs);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CatalogModule).then(platformRef => {
  const config = require('./config.json');
  (<any>window).__APP_CONFIG__ = config;

  const appMountPoint = document.querySelector('[xs-app-mountpoint]');
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(appMountPoint, [Ng1Module], {strictDi: false});

  console.log('hybrid app bootstrapped');
})
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

However, at the moment Webpack is putting the whole config.json file content into one main.js file after compilation which is what I don't want. I'd like to fetch the config file and use it as a Window variable but keeping the config.json file separated from the main.js.

How it is possible? I tried using

```
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'utf8'));
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: you can put it inside the assets folder and you can fetch it from HttpClient.

Comment: How can I use HttpClient inside my main.ts file? It is not a class that I can inject that to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by using the Fetch API:

```
fetch('config.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((config) => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CatalogModule).then(platformRef => {
      (<any>window).__APP_CONFIG__ = config;
      const appMountPoint = document.querySelector('[xs-app-mountpoint]');
      const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
      upgrade.bootstrap(appMountPoint, [Ng1Module], {strictDi: false});

      console.log('hybrid app bootstrapped');
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
```